# EJB utf-8 characters not persisted

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, ejb

I have an **ejb 3** application and deployed it in Glassfish 3.1 server.

I have **ExamDtl** entity with exmId & qustion fields, when i persist entity in database i found value of qustion field become ????.
I have set UTF8 collation in table and I can insert utf-8 characters just fine with sql using like "INSERT INTO..."

I  have also set following property in sun-resources.xml file

```
<property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exam_databse?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
```

Is there any setting for utf 8 in ejb?

Comment: How are you viewing these characters? You really need to work out *exactly* where you're losing data - see http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2014/01/20/diagnosing-issues-with-reversible-data-transformations.aspx which has a C# slant on it, but is really general.

Comment: Do the utf8 chars appear in your mysql tables?

Comment: its appear ????? in database.